# OpenCV undistort

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics

I'm using `OpenCV` (2.4.8) on Windows 7 and I'm trying to calibrate and undistort images taken from a GoPro camera.

The calibration is done using the live option on the GoPro via WiFi.

I'm using this code (taken from [Here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/) and modified a bit by me):

```
int numBoards = 10;
int numCornersHor = 9;
int numCornersVer = 6;

int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;

vector<Point2f> corners;
int successes=0;

Mat image;
Mat gray_image;
*videoCapture >> image;
cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
vector<Point3f> obj;
for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
{
    obj.push_back(Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));
}

while(successes<numBoards)
{
    bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if(found)
    {
        cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
        imshow("Image", image);
        imshow("Grayscale Image", gray_image);
    }


    *videoCapture >> image;

    int key = waitKey(1);
    if(key==27)
        return false;

    if(key==' ' && found!=0)
    {
        image_points.push_back(corners);
        object_points.push_back(obj);
        printf("Snap stored!\n");

        successes++;

        if(successes>=numBoards)
            break;
    }
}
//cameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
FileStorage fs(CALIBRATION_XML_FILE, FileStorage::WRITE);
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;
//cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
//cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;
cv::calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
time_t rawtime; time(&rawtime);

fs << "calibrationDate" << asctime(localtime(&rawtime));
fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
fs.release();
Mat imageUndistorted;
while(true)
{
    *videoCapture >> image;
    undistort(image, imageUndistorted, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

    imshow("Original", image);
    imshow("Undistorted", imageUndistorted);

    int key = waitKey(1);
    if(key==27)
        return true;
}
```

and after the calibration ends, the `Undistoreted` window shows the undistorted video feed very well.

These matrices are saved to an XML file via OpenCV's FileStorage.

I then, after closing the application and running it in another mode in order to distort images saved before (also taken with the same camera).

First I'm reading the XML file (I printed the matrices after loading, they match the XML file so the loading is fine) using again the FileStorage class

I'm then using this code to undistort the images:

```
Mat outMat;
undistort(inputImage, outMat, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
return outMat;
```

But the results are horrible.

Input image:
[image]

Undistorted image:
[image]

Am I missing something that needs to be done before calling `undistort`?

Thanks

**EDIT**

If it matters, this is the XML file that was saved using the FileStorage:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<calibrationDate>"Fri May 09 17:12:58 2014&#x0a;"</calibrationDate>
<cameraMatrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>3</rows>
    <cols>3</cols>
    <dt>d</dt>
    <data>
        2.2187712262636470e+002 0. 2.2825108444773281e+002 0.
        2.1495762743910956e+002 1.0916298701649789e+002 0. 0. 1.</data></cameraMatrix>
<distCoeffs type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>1</rows>
    <cols>5</cols>
    <dt>d</dt>
    <data>
        -3.0914887115528705e-001 1.1236389287266597e-001
         2.0789692021046750e-002 -2.6151676079193696e-003
        -1.7270919007796915e-002</data></distCoeffs>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: cv::calibrateCamera() returns an error value. unless that is small(<0.5), you'll have to redo it with a better variation of poses. also, use a rectangular(not a quadratic) board. yours seems to be 11x11. the quadratic one is rotation symmetric at 90° this will give you that kind of 'bottle view'

Comment: Thanks. But if the calibration is bad, why when it ends and it uses the same matrices to do the `undistort` it looks great? Only after opening the app again, reading the matrices and unddistorting it gets like this? But I'll check the error, thanks.

Comment: ^^ sorry, don't understand last comment.

Comment: If you'd look at the calibration code (or the link to it) you'll see that at the end, it uses `undistort` and then display it. When this is done, everything looks great. I then save the matrices, and use them in a different app -> I load the matrices and call `undistort` - now they look bad.

Comment: ah, ok. understood, but no idea atm.

Comment: I know this might be a bit late, but I had a similar problem a couple of days ago. What was wrong was in my second program, my `inputImage` was changed to another size, hence the current camera matrix should also be scaled to reflect that. From the openCV doc- **The camera matrix and the distortion parameters can be determined using calibrateCamera() . If the resolution of images is different from the resolution used at the calibration stage, f_x, f_y, c_x and c_y need to be scaled accordingly, while the distortion coefficients remain the same.**

Comment: It's looks like you using a different resolution at undistrort then the one you have used at calibration
You need to scale up your camera matrix
regards